# Query product's image path by category WooCommerce database?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql, sql

I am writing a small query to grab image path and object ID from Woo_Commerce database. I am join taxonomy and relationship table to achieve this but somehow I am making mistake I can't realize. I have my category comparison set and path is coming from post_meta but somehow not giving the two columns. The category that I am intersted is just the term_ID that I want to pass (16). So I want all object ID that has term_ID 16 and the second column is their image path.

Object ID | ImgPath

```
SELECT 
object_id as productID, 
meta_value as imgPath

FROM wp_term_relationships as wp_re
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pthGiver
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as termIDgiver
on wp_re.object_id = pthGiver.post_id AND
pthGiver.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
WHERE termIDgiver.`term_taxonomy_id` = '16'
```

[image]

As you can see in the following image WordPress is grabbing all the products and their images by category I want `term_taxonomy_id` = '16' which is diamond. How is WordPress filtering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query WC products based on category from database?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/349659/how-to-query-wc-products-based-on-category-from-database)

Comment: just deleted it.